# Why Linux as a router doesn't forward all of the packets of my protocol?

Tags: linux, ip

I'm implementing my own protocol over IP layer and I'm setting iph->protocol to let's say 150 value. AFAIK this protocol number 150 is not reserved for any existing protocol. I'm using two qemu guest machines with Linux and a router also on Linux between them.

The problem is with forwarding packets with my protocol 150 through this Linux router between these qemu machines. This router forwards only a few from fixed number of 10 packets. The issue is that the router is forwarding non-deterministic number of these packets in range of 1..number_of_sent_packets/2. The interesting thing is that the router is forwarding maximum half of sent packets. I just didn't notice that the router forwarded more than half of them.

Isn't the role of router to forward only IP packets without taking a look what is transported inside the packet as a payload? I'm using standard (vanilla) Linux kernel on router.

What should I check or set on Linux to let forwarding my packets? Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, problem solved. The issue was in calculation of checksum. Now Linux as a router is forwarding all the IP packets.